# Magento - Wrong log file path

Tags: magento2, monolog

I was fixing an issue in Magento and I found a suggestion to run

```
composer update
```

and

```
setup:upgrade
```

After this I fell in an error for wrong log file path:

```
/var/www/html//var/log/system.log
```

I found this error in var/log/exception.log

```
The stream or file "/var/www/html//var/log/system.log" could not be opened:
 failed to open stream: Permission denied {"exception":"[object] 
(UnexpectedValueException(code: 0): The stream or file 
\"/var/www/html//var/log/system.log\" could not be opened: failed to open
 stream: Permission denied at 
/var/www/html/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php:107)"
} []
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the permissions of the `/var/log/system.log` file within `/var/www/html` directory?

`Permission denied` signifies that the file is inaccessible.

The file must have `0664` permissions in order for PHP to be able to write to that file.